# Laravel Collection <> Model hybrid for non DB Entities?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

A pretty simple question, but apparently not such a simple answer:

Is there a hybrid between Collections and Eloquent Models that uses the features of dynamic methods but not linked to a db connection?

e.q. One of my most favorite features of Eloquent models are the accessors and mutators. But I don't really want the overhead (or accidental 500 SQL error) that comes with Eloquent models.

Is there a Collection set somewhere that will offer those features, without the overhead of Eloquent?

I often find myself resorting to just making my object a Model ... but honestly it's more like "Record" that's not connected to any back-end data sources.

Comment: With `get` & `setAttribute` you're referring to `Accessors` & `Mutators`? Afaik this only works on models

Comment: Yes, those. That would be the official names for them. I'll update the comment.

Comment: Yeah, probably only works with actual models. You can create your own class that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/jenssegers/model), but I do not find it very useful. It provides some convenience.

You can also create a class (your own model class) and implement the required features and all of your "models" that do not need to connect to the database extend that class. So you have full control of it, basically, you take some good ideas from laravel (the ones you like and want to use) and implement yourself.